# What is the noun for "removing"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The following are example pairs of sentences where a word is used as a verb and then a noun.

> I am rotating this.
> This is a rotation.
>
> I am moving this.
> This is a movement.

What would be the equal sentence for "removing"?

> I am removing this.
> This is a _______.

My first thought would be "removation", but that isn't a word (as far as I know).

Comment: This is a ***removal***: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/removal

Comment: Could you post that as an answer? @Josh61

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The noun form is ***[removal](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/removal):***

Meaning and usage notes:

> - [uncountable] ***removal (of somebody/something)***  the act of taking somebody/something away from a particular place.
>
>   - *Clearance of the site required the removal of a number of trees.
>       The removal of a tumour. 
>       Allegations of abuse led to the removal of several children from their families.*
> - [uncountable] ***removal (of something)*** the act of getting rid of something
>
>   - *stain removal, 
>       the removal of trade barriers*
> - [uncountable] ***removal (of somebody)*** the act of dismissing somebody from their job.
>
>   - synonym dismissal, 
>       *events leading to the removal of the president from office*
> - [countable] ***(British English) an act of taking furniture, etc.from one house to another***
>
>   - *house removals, 
>       a removal company/firm, 
>       When are the removal men coming?*

(OLD)